# How do I extend the legend which displays the time progression (as a change of color) of my movement path in a D3 scatterplot?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, scatter-plot

I created a scatterplot in D3.js which is basically showing a person's 2D movement from a top-down perspective. To visualize the time, I used the D3-method interpolateBlues, so that our dots get another color as time passes (starting from white to dark blue). Our movement data (X and Y coordinates), as well as the corresponding time value (passed seconds) are stored in a JSON-Array called movementdata.

I also created a tooltip function, which shows the exact X and Y coordinates and the corresponding time in seconds when you hover over a certain point in the scatterplot.

Problem: I have added an additional legend on the right side which appears, however it is way too small. When I increase the height value, it gets larger but only towards the bottom. So only the dark blue values get stretched in length. I can't find a way to stretch or rather scale the entire legend so that the other colors will be stretched as well.

I will post screenshots as well as my code to make it more clear.

```
// Add legend
var legend = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - space) + "," + space + ")")
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("height", 10)

var colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateBlues)
  .domain([0, d3.max(movementdata, function(d) { return d.t; })]);

legend.selectAll("rect")
  .data(movementdata)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.t; })
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.t); });

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", -30)
  .attr("y", -5)
  .style("font-size", "12px")
  .text("Passed Time (s)");

var legendTicks = [0, d3.max(movementdata, function(d) { return d.t; }) / 2, d3.max(movementdata, function(d) { return d.t; })];

legend.selectAll(".legend-text")
  .data(legendTicks)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "legend-text")
  .attr("x", 25)
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d; })
  .attr("dy", "1em") 
  .style("font-size", "12px")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

[image: Movement scatterplot with legend which is too small]

Adjusting the height attribute (by increasing it) doesn't solve the problem as you can see here, it only gets worse

[image: Increasing the height doesn't solve the problem, it only gets worse]

Comment: I met a traveler in an antique land, who said, "please do not tag your titles, ye mighty; see [ask] for more wisdom and take the [tour] to avoid great despair".

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what the actual question was... kept reading the question and looking at the tooltips and couldn't figure out what was wrong.. until I realized that the scale is the problem. Try to call out your issue early on and clearly, and then include more specific details.

Comment: @alecf The scale is not the problem. It's the legend. I mentioned the legend in the title as well as in the description. But thanks, I've edited the description a bit now.

Answer (score 0):

Creating SVG Group for Legend:

An SVG group element () with the class "legend" is appended to an SVG (svg) element.
width and space variables are used to position the legend within the SVG.
Color Scale:

A sequential color scale (colorScale) using the "Blues" color interpolation from D3 is created.
The domain of the color scale is set from 0 to the maximum value of 't' in the movementdata.
Legend Rectangles
Appending Rectangles to Legend:
movementdata is bound to the rectangles within the legend.
Each data point in movementdata is represented by a rectangle.
The rectangles are filled with colors based on the 't' value using the color scale.
Legend Text
Adding Label to Legend:
A text element indicating "Passed Time (s)" is added to the legend.
Ticks on Legend
Adding Tick Marks to Legend:
An array legendTicks is created with 3 elements: 0, half the maximum 't' value, and the maximum 't' value from movementdata.
Text elements corresponding to these tick values are added to the legend.
Points to Note:
The positioning of elements within the legend is done using the 'y' attribute for rectangles and text.
The text elements for tick marks are positioned relative to the rectangles and labeled with values from legendTicks.
This code creates a legend with colored rectangles representing the range of 't' values in the movementdata, along with corresponding tick marks and labels denoting the scale of passed time in seconds.

Comment: This smells like a botpost. Please note that AI-generated content is prohibited on SO.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).